# get last outgoing call status in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova-plugins, oracle-maf

We are initiating a call from application(non voip app) by passing a tel url with phone number to document.location.href  in javascript.
We are trying to implement a cordova plugin to get the call states once the call is completed.
In android we are using PhoneStateListener to achieve this

Do we have a simiar service in ios?
I tried using the CXCallObserver as below

added property:

```
 @property ( nonatomic ) CXCallObserver *callObserver;
```

In pluginInitialize added,

```
CXCallObserver *callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
[callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
self.callObserver = callObserver;
```

and added the below method

```
 (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
        NSString* callstatus = @"Call Changed";
        if (call == nil || call.hasEnded == YES) {
            NSLog(@"CXCallState : Disconnected");
            callstatus = @"Call Disconnected";
        }

        if (call.isOutgoing == YES && call.hasConnected == NO) {
            NSLog(@"CXCallState : Dialing");
            callstatus = @"Call Dialing";
        }

        if (call.isOutgoing == NO  && call.hasConnected == NO && call.hasEnded == NO && call != nil) {
            NSLog(@"CXCallState : Incoming");
            callstatus = @"Call Incoming";
        }

        if (call.hasConnected == YES && call.hasEnded == NO) {
            NSLog(@"CXCallState : Connected");
            callstatus = @"Call Connected";
        }
    }
```

But callObserver method is not getting invoked when call state changes.

I am very new to ios. Is there anything I am missing to add? Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: see this for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933109/callkit-doesnt-recognize-connected-info-of-outgoing-call

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, ours is a non voip app.Hence we are not having the SIP event handlers. is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with logging using our framework.
We are now able to see the call states using the above implementation